# When to use which material design svg folder

Tags: svg, icons, material-design, google-material-icons

In the [material design icons github repo](https://github.com/google/material-design-icons), each svg folder has two subfolders, [design](https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/tree/master/action/svg/design) and [production](https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/tree/master/action/svg/production). They have the same size (shown by `du -s`), but a `diff` shows differing content. (EDIT: `du` only shows block size, actual sizes are different as of the comment).

Which folder is for which purpose? Especially: which folder is intended for combining icons?

Comment: production looks to be a minified version of design.

Comment: @ccprog: Thanks, that makes sense. Why do they have exactly the same size?

Comment: By size you mean source text size? As far as I can see, most loose a few bytes. I am not going to comment on whether minification is a usefull process.

Comment: @ccprog: Source file size. `for i in $(ls -F | grep /); do echo $i; du -s $i/svg/production $i/svg/design; done` yielded the exact same sizes

Comment: `du` returns disk space usage based on block size, differences are small, i. e. ic_accessible_24px.svg: design 561 bytes, production 507 bytes. If you collect the icons into sprites, there might be a resulting size difference on the disk. But that is not the relevant figure, that would be transmission size via http. If you consider the effect of transport compression, I would for a sprite with all icons doubt that this form of minifaction gets a reduction of even one TCP block.

Comment: @ccprog: wow, thank you for that info. Any idea which folder to use if you want to compose icons? Better the design folder? How is the minimization done?